# PHPExcel output file is empty

Tags: phpexcel

I downloaded PHPExcel library but could not use it. I am using one of the examples in the Library but it downloads an empty excel file. Here is my code.

```
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("document");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="deneme.xls"');
```

Am i forgetting something here? It is simple but downloaded excel file is empty. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT:
Solved: I have to add these lines:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: If you're using a content type of application/vnd.ms-excel and a file extension of .xls, you should be using the Excel5 writer; not Excel2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to instantiate a writer and then save

Answer (score 3):

Add this:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
die();
```